# jodd cannot manage to inject two beans

Tags: jodd

I have a DAO and a Service class each implements a interface:

```
public interface TemperatureDao extends GenericDAO<TemperatureLog> {

    public abstract List<TemperatureLog> getLastHourTemperatures();
}

@PetiteBean(value="temperatureDao",wiring=WiringMode.AUTOWIRE)
public class TemperatureDaoImpl extends GenericAbstractDAO<TemperatureLog> implements TemperatureDao {

    @Override
    public List<TemperatureLog> getLastHourTemperatures(){                  
        //do stuff here
        return temps;
    }
}
```

and

```
public interface TemperatureService {

    public abstract boolean save(TemperatureLog t);
    public abstract List<TemperatureLog> getLastHoutTemperatures();
}

@PetiteBean(value="temperatureService",wiring=WiringMode.AUTOWIRE)
public class TemperatureServiceImpl extends GenericService implements TemperatureService {

    @PetiteInject
    private TemperatureDao temperatureDao;      

    public TemperatureDao getTemperatureDao() {
        return temperatureDao;
    }

    public void setTemperatureDao(TemperatureDao temperatureDao) {
        this.temperatureDao = temperatureDao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(TemperatureLog t){

        try {
            temperatureDao.saveOrUpdate(t);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transaction(propagation = JtxPropagationBehavior.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, readOnly = true,isolation=JtxIsolationLevel.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED)
    public List<TemperatureLog> getLastHoutTemperatures(){

        return temperatureDao.getLastHourTemperatures();        
    }   
}
```

and the problem is that `temperatureDao` is not injected as i get `NullPointerException` here:

```
return temperatureDao.getLastHourTemperatures();
```

The logs looks fine to me :

```
127 [DEBUG] j.p.PetiteBeans.registerPetiteBean:244 - Registering bean: temperatureDao of type: TemperatureDaoImpl in: SingletonScope using wiring mode: AUTOWIRE
128 [DEBUG] j.p.ProxettaBuilder.process:187 - processing: ro/videanuadrian/smartHome/dao/impl/TemperatureDaoImpl
128 [DEBUG] j.p.ProxettaBuilder.define:228 - proxy not applied ro.videanuadrian.smartHome.dao.impl.TemperatureDaoImpl
134 [DEBUG] j.p.PetiteBeans.registerPetiteBean:244 - Registering bean: temperatureService of type: TemperatureServiceImpl in: SingletonScope using wiring mode: AUTOWIRE
135 [DEBUG] j.p.ProxettaBuilder.process:187 - processing: ro/videanuadrian/smartHome/services/impl/TemperatureServiceImpl
139 [DEBUG] j.p.ProxettaBuilder.define:243 - proxy created ro.videanuadrian.smartHome.services.impl.TemperatureServiceImpl
```

So, any idea what I'm I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting new answer to explain better what is going on.

What happens here is that you have proxy created on `TemperatureServiceImpl` and registered it as a `PetiteBean`, which is perfectly correct :) So, Petite container gets the proxified class, which is a subclass of your service implementation.

When Petite does the wiring, it is scanning the proxy class and, therefore, it can not see the annotated private field in the super class (which is the original `TemperatureServiceImpl`).

You can fix this in two ways:

1. either by removing `private` modifier (and use anything else) - than container will 'see' the field in the subclass, or
2. simply annotating the e.g. `getTemperatureDao()` method with `@PetiteInject` and leaving the field as it is.

Hope this explains what is going on. I will try to address this in upcoming 3.6 release.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the issue was that `temperatureDao` was declared as `private`. I have change it to default and now it works.

Comment: Hi Adrian! I am trying to reproduce this with latest codebase and it is still working with `private` (as it should:). Also, if you use `AUTOWIRE` you don't need to use `@PetiteInject` on field, since everything will be autowired. Btw, you can set `AUTOWIRE` to be your default wiring mode, so you don't need to write it all the time. Anyway, if you have time please [contact me](http://jodd.org/contact.html) as I wish to help.

Comment: btw, are you sure `temperatureDao` was in `TemperatureServiceImpl`? From described behavior it seems like this field was declared in subclass?